# callback function in javascript replace() is not called

Tags: javascript, regex, cookies

I would like to replace the `domain` of a cookie string:

```
var cookieText = 'test=value; path=/; domain=.mydomain.com';

cookieText.replace(/[Dd]omain=(\.?)([a-zA-Z0-9\.]*);/, function(match, dot, domain){
    return dot + myfunction(domain)
});
```

But it seems mycallback function is never called. What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you regex doesn't match any substring in your `cookieText` string. This happens because you pattern expects a `;` at the end of each substring, but that doesn't happen to `domain=.mydomain.com`. Try this regex instead:

```
/[Dd]omain=(\.?)([a-zA-Z0-9\.]*);?/
```

Then it will work:

```
var cookieText = 'test=value; path=/; domain=.mydomain.com';

cookieText.replace(/[Dd]omain=(\.?)([a-zA-Z0-9\.]*);/, function(match, dot, domain){
    console.log(match);
    return dot + myfunction(domain);
});
```